# How can I get the star ratign system to display the stars correctly in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rating-system

I'm creating a product review comment section with a star rating system but I can't get the rating to display correctly once the comment is added to the comment section.

This is the code I use to create and add a new review, the function createRating gets each star and adds the class .checked based on the rating introduced by the user. The problem is when I have more than one comment, because the querySelectorAll gets the stars from all of the comments in the page and not the comment just created. How can I select the stars from the comment just created?

```
function publishReview() {
    const comment = document.createElement('div');
    comment.classList.add('review-comment');
    comment.innerHTML = `
    <div class="review-header">
        <div class="rating">
            <span class="review-star fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="review-star fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="review-star fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="review-star fa fa-star"></span>
            <span class="review-star fa fa-star"></span>
        </div>    
        <p class="review-date">1 abr. 2023</p>
    </div>
    <p class="review-text">${reviewTextInput.value}</p>
    <span>Helpful?<button class="helpful-button">Yes</button> <button class="helpful-button">No</button></span>`;
    
    commentSection.appendChild(comment);
    popupDisplayNone();

    const ratingStars = document.querySelectorAll('.review-star');
    createRating(ratingStars, currentStar);
    
}
```

If any more information is required, please ask, new to this.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to add a `data-id` attribute to the review `div` (the one with the 'review-comment' class). If you have a database that stores reviews, you could use that one, otherwise you can generate one in javascript.

Adding the `data-id` attribute can be achieved with the [setAttribute API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
comment.setAttribute("data-id", {{ your review id }});
```

Then, filter the review stars by changing your query selector like this:

```
const ratingStars = document.querySelectorAll(".review-comment[data-id='{{your review id}}'] .review-star");
```

**Edit**
MaikeruDev's answer is simpler, so that is probably better for now. But if you ever need to access a certain comment again, my answer will offer a more persistent solution.